# Recursive file search with extensions and wildcard searches in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a code that searches through chosen folder for files with all documents/graphics extensions that contain specific words in their filenames. I couldn't find any similiar examples and I've tried few different approaches with this 1 being the closest:

```
private void startButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    File startingPath = dirChooser.getCurrentDirectory();
    String[] extensions = new String[] { 
        "txt", "doc", "docx", "jpg", "jpeg", "pdf", "odt", "png", "bmp"}; 
    // there are about 20 different patterns like the ones below
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*password.*|.*user.*|.*profile.*"); 
    List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(
              startingPath, extensions, true);
    files.forEach((file) -> {
        if (file.isFile()){
            Matcher m = p.matcher(file.toString().toLowerCase());
            if (m.matches()) {
                filesArea.append(file.toString() + "\n");
                noOfFiles++;
            }      
        }
    });
}
```

The extensions search works perfect but for some reason the patterns search works only with some folders and not others. I'm sure there are better approaches but this one seemed the easiest and (almost) worked. Any ideas how I could get it fully working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about that:

```
Files.walk(dirChooser.getCurrentDirectory().toPath())
    .filter(file -> Pattern.matches(".*password.*|.*user.*|.*profile.*", file.getFileName().toString()) && accept(file))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The accept function looks like:

```
public boolean accept(Path e)
{
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Extensions", "txt", "doc", "docx", "jpg", "jpeg", "pdf", "odt", "png", "bmp");
    return filter.accept(e.toFile());
}
```

This code will list a paths to files that contain your word and specific extension. However it is a stream so you can do with it whatever you'd like.